# htaccess causing an Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on                                                            
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images?                                       
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api.php?                                      
    RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?path=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Not sure why it is causing an error, would be really appreciated if someone could help.

Comment: Please do add details in your question, what sample links you are hitting and from which file in backend they should get served etc. Its not clear as of now, thank you.

Comment: Please check your `error.log` file.

Comment: This looks like an endless rewriting loop, since `/index.php` will get rewritten again, since both conditions match, obviously. You could easily answer that yourself by taking a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can simply read what the issue is instead of having to guess or ask.